# SQL LIKE Operator

Tags: sql, sql-like

I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    dictionary t1, 
    dictionary t2
WHERE t1.category <> t2.category
    AND t1.tag <> t2.tag
    AND t1.word LIKE '% t2.word %';
```

How to write `'% t2.word %'` part of the SQL to get correct results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 select * 
   from dictionary t1, 
        dictionary t2 -- <- Is there an intentional Cartesian Join?
  where t1.category <> t2.category and 
        t1.tag <> t2.tag and 
        t1.word like '% ' || t2.word || ' %'; -- <- check spaces!
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the column.

```
select * 
from dictionary t1, dictionary t2 
where t1.category<>t2.category and t1.tag<>t2.tag and t1.word like '% ' + t2.word + ' %';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from dictionary t1, dictionary t2 
where t1.category<>t2.category and t1.tag<>t2.tag and t1.word like '%'+ t2.word +'%';
```

Comment: It gives ERROR: operator does not exist: unknown + text
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Yeah if you'd said Oracle I would have given you the || answer!

Comment: I don't use Oracle, I use postgresql. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

this is what you are looking for:

```
select * 
from dictionary t1, dictionary t2 
where t1.category<>t2.category and t1.tag<>t2.tag and t1.word like '% ' + t2.word + ' %';
```